# (InputMap)UIManager.get("TextField.focusInputMap") not work

Tags: java, swing

I try this code to override shortcut key on Mac OS, but it not working..

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name", "").toUpperCase().startsWith("MAC")) {
    InputMap im = (InputMap) UIManager.get("TextField.focusInputMap");
    int MASK = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, MASK), DefaultEditorKit.selectAllAction);
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, MASK), DefaultEditorKit.copyAction);
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, MASK), DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction);
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, MASK), DefaultEditorKit.cutAction);
}
```

However, this does... by replace to particular TextField..

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name", "").toUpperCase().startsWith("MAC")) {
    InputMap im = (InputMap) txtOutput.getInputMap();
    int MASK = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, MASK), DefaultEditorKit.selectAllAction);
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, MASK), DefaultEditorKit.copyAction);
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, MASK), DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction);
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, MASK), DefaultEditorKit.cutAction);
}
```

Is it possible to override shortcut key to all TextField at once ?

I'm using java swing.

Comment: What do you mean by "but it not working"?

Comment: It's still cannot use copy, paste of mac shortcut key on the first code snippet.

Comment: Is there an exception that gets thrown?  How do you know that it is failing at that specific line?

Comment: No exception throw, it's becasue second code snippet is working. When I point to actual Textfield

Comment: What's the look and feel?

Comment: I'm new to java swing, what is look and feel?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/LookAndFeel.html. do `System.out.println(UIManager.getLookAndFeel());`

Comment: [Nimbus Look and Feel - javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you are doing right now because you didn't give us the MCVE but you need to change the property before creating the swing components:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Test());
    }

    Test() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        InputMap im = (InputMap) UIManager.get("TextField.focusInputMap");
        int MASK = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_B, MASK), DefaultEditorKit.cutAction);

        JTextField tf = new JTextField("FF");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(tf);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```